# How to filter a RxJS Map Oberservable

Tags: angular, dictionary, rxjs

i am currently struggeling by filtering a Map Observable with RxJS.
What i try to do is to do reduce my Map-Object by a filter function before subscribing to it.

I init the Subject like this:

```
public myObjects: ReplaySubject<Map<number, MyClass>> = new ReplaySubject<Map<number, MyClass>>(1);
```

And that's how I try to filter:

```
public subscribeToIncomingObjects() {
this.myObjects.map( (currentValue:Map<number, MyObject>) => Array.from(currentValue.values())).filter(
  (con:myObject, index) => {
    return someCondition;
  }
);
 }
```

For some reason con is of type Array and not a single instance. I would really appreciate any advise.

Comment: You're returning an Array with `Array.from(...)` from the previous `.map()` call. That's why the following `filter()` gets Array and not the original object.

Comment: Hi @martin, thanks for the explanation. For some reason I expected to get single values of the array inside my filter function as described here: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html . Doesn't Rx.Observable.range(X,Y) actually generate an Array Observable?

Comment: No, this creates an `Observable<number>` instance that emits every number in that range as a separate item.

Answer (score 1):

First things first,

You are dealing with an `Observable` :

```js
this.myObjects.map( (currentValue:Map<number, MyObject>) => Array.from(currentValue.values()))
```

returns an `Observable<MyObject[]>`. So if you call `.filter()` on that `Observable`, you are filtering Observable's broadcast.

You could just call your filter like this :

```js
public subscribeToIncomingObjects() {
  this.myObjects.map((currentValue: Map < number, MyObject > ) => {
    return Array.from(currentValue.values())
      .filter((con: myObject, index) => someCondition);
  });
}
```

**BUT** you would still get an array, if you need a single instance you'd better use `Array.prototype.find()` if it is available :

```js
public subscribeToIncomingObjects() {
  this.myObjects.map((currentValue: Map < number, MyObject > ) => {
    return Array.from(currentValue.values())
      .find((con: myObject, index) => someCondition);
  });
}
```

or, still using `Array.prototype.filter()`:

```js
public subscribeToIncomingObjects() {
  this.myObjects.map((currentValue: Map < number, MyObject > ) => {
    return Array.from(currentValue.values())
      .filter((con: myObject, index) => someCondition)[0];
  });
}
```